# Why Html.TextBox with array index prefixes , can not read model data that are constructed as a Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have two model classes; skill & skill Level. where each Skill can have many SkilLevels:-

```
public partial class Skill
    {
        public Skill()
        {
            this.SkillLevels = new HashSet<SkillLevel>();
            this.SkillLevelStaffs = new HashSet<SkillLevelStaff>();
            this.SkillVersionHistories = new HashSet<SkillVersionHistory>();
            this.Customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
            this.LinkToKBs = new HashSet<LinkToKB>();
        }

        public int SkillID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsAllCustomer { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
       //code goes here



        public virtual ICollection<SkillLevel> SkillLevels { get; set; }

    }

public partial class SkillLevel
    {
        public int SkillID { get; set; }
        public int LevelID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string TestProcess { get; set; }

        public virtual Level Level { get; set; }
        public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
    }
```

now inside the Skill create/Edit view i am displaying a four pairs of SkillLevel fields

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       {

<div class="form-group">
@Html.Label("SkillLevels[" + i.ToString() + "].TestProcess", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.TextArea("SkillLevels[" + i.ToString() + "].TestProcess",new { @class = "form-control", rows=10}) 
</div>

@Html.Label("SkillLevels[" + i.ToString() + "].Description", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.TextArea("SkillLevels[" + i.ToString() + "].Description") 
@Html.ValidationMessage("SkillLevels[" + i.ToString() + "].Description",new { @class = "form-control", rows=10})
</div></div>
string v = (i + 1).ToString();
@Html.Hidden("SkillLevels[" + i.ToString() + "].SkillID",Model.SkillID)
@Html.Hidden("SkillLevels[" + i.ToString() + "].LevelID", v)
       }
```

this will work well inside the create view , where four pairs of Textprocess + Description are going to be displayed and posted back as a `collection<SkillLevels>`, but if i have the same code inside the edit view, then the four pairs of SkillLevel will always be empty when i visit the edit viw,, seems that the TextBox with array of indexses can not read the `Collection<SkillLevels>`?? so inside the edit view i have to define a foreach to get this work:-

```
@{
int i=0;
}
@foreach(var s in Model.SkillLevels)
{
  <div>
    @Html.Editor("SkillLevels[" + i.ToString() + "].TestProcess", new { @Value = s.TestProcess })
```

but i am trying to use the same view for both Edit + Create. can anyone adivce ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use magic strings. I do about the same the follwoing way:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SkillLevels.Length; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SkillLevels[i].TestProcess, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.SkillLevels[i].TestProcess, new { @class = "form-control", rows=10}) 
    </div>
    ...
}
```

In case of a new item you need to "prefill" the collection with 4 empty items...

If you use `foreach` to iterate over collections the model-binding does not work, hence the use of `for` and `m.SkillLevels[i]`.

Comment: but where i need to prefill" the collection with 4 empty items... inside the action method ?second question why model binder does not work on foreach ?

Comment: @johnG: Doesn't really matter - just somewhere before the `for`-loop, but I do it inside the action by supplying an "empty item" as a model...

Comment: ok thanks , and what about the two hidden fields SkillID & LevelID , where incase of Create they both will = zero, while on edit they will contain the realted ids ?

Comment: ok i tried your approach but i will get the following exception "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<SkillManagement.Models.SkillLevel>'" ? not sure what is the problem ..

Comment: @johnG: Try using e.g. `List` instead of `ICollection` inside your `Skill` class. Why are you using `ICollection` and `HashSet` anyhow?

Comment: yes i use database first approach and i will get .edmx containing the mapped model classes,, and edmx implements any navigation property as Icollection  . can you check my original question, i provide the "public partial class Skill" which is automatically generated for me ,, and yes i have icollectino with hachset created for me..

Comment: @johnG: Sorry, can't help you with DB-first, as I use Code-First, but I *think* you can tell DB-first to generate `DbContext` and CF-entities instead of *.edmx. Bottom line: You need indexed access for model-binding to work and `ICollection` does not support that. If you can't change your DB model you need to introduce a separate view model...

Comment: ok i got your point , so i will keep my current approach as is ,, atleast it works well, but ogcourse not the best solution,, i might consider using dbconteaxt & CF-entites maybe in the future..thanks

Comment: Although this might not be related to my original question. But can you advice what other things I might not be able to achieve with ICollections compared to IList,, as this might give me a clearer picture if I really need to use CF-entities instead of .edmx?

Comment: @johnG: Sorry, but just search "ICollection vs IList" and you will find your answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you can make your edit view with for each loop iterated over SkillLevels collection and want use the same view to proceed with the create - the first idea I have is simply adding the four empty elements to the collection in the action method which returns model for the create view.

To do this you should provide nullable variables in your model

```
public partial class SkillLevel
    {
        public int? SkillID { get; set; }
        public int? LevelID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string TestProcess { get; set; }

        public virtual Level Level { get; set; }
        public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
    }
```

Last two I think doesn't matter.

And then in your controller it should look more or less like that:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var model = new SomeModel();
   model.SkillLevels = new List<SkillLevel>(4);
   for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
      model.SkillLevels.Add(new SkillLevel());
   }
   return View("~/sth/Edit", model); //here should be path to your view
}
```